# Send data from native android app to Ionic local index file

Tags: javascript, android, html, ionic-framework, ionic-native

We have few features in native and few features in Ionic(Ionic's www in our android project's assets folder). We are trying to load Ionic's local index.html from Android webView.

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html?country=IN")
```

It loads index.html but skips query parameter. How to create a bridge kind of thing where we can load Ionic pages with extra information from native Android webView.

Offcourse, Ionic should process the extra information and take action. But, as of now local html file strips any query parameter in url.